# WP site homepage displays url link at beginning of each featured post

Tags: urls, homepage, featured-post

[image: []Home page on my wordpress site displays url code before showing the text of my featured posts. They display normally once the post is called in their respective pages so the issue is just on the home page. How do I prevent this from happening? Screenshot of the problem and address for my home page included here.[2](http://myredsabbatical.com/)

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template file for single post page.
 *
 * @package    The Daybook
 * @version    1.1
 * @author     Elite Layers <admin@elitelayers.com>
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2017, Elite Layers
 * @link       http://demo.elitelayers.com/thedaybook/
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU General Public License v2 or later
 */
 get_header(); ?>

    <div id="thedaybook-content" class="section">

        <div class="block">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
<?php /* insert affiliate disclosure */
$affiliate_disclaimer = get_field( 'ad_affiliate_disclaimer' );
if( in_array( 'yes', $affiliate_disclaimer ) ) { ?>
    <p class="disclaimer"><strong>Heads up:</strong> My posts may contain affiliate links. If you buy something through one of those links, it won't cost you a penny more, but I might get a small commission to help to keep the lights on. I don't recommend any products I have not tried and love. <a class="nowrap" href="/legal/#affiliate"><small>Learn More &raquo;</small></a></p>
<?php } /* end affiliate disclosure */ ?>
                    <main id="main" class="<?php echo esc_attr(thedaybook_content_class());?>">

                         <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                             <?php get_template_part('parts/content','single'); ?>

                         <?php endwhile; ?>

                         <?php endif; ?>

                     </main>

                     <aside class="<?php echo esc_attr(thedaybook_sidebar_class());?>">
                        <?php get_sidebar();?>
                     </aside>

                </div>

             </div>

         </div>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: please read this post on how to [ask a good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you wish for users to help you.

Comment: Hello Marcela, welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately, the offending code is not the one you post. It could be anywhere in the theme The Daybook you are using. Your best course of action is probably to contact the theme's author.

Comment: Hi cjbj - that would make sense if this issue was there since the beginning. However, it was fine and only started appearing today after I was playing with SEO and affiliate disclaimer plug in. What puzzles me is why this issue is only on the home page but not on the actual post pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code,
Maybe you have entered post url code with content

I mean like.(URL code) (Content Code)

I have checked your concern and i found these solutions.

If still facing problem then paste here your code so i can understand that.

Comment: I added the code in issue description now. I today added code in the post code to show affiliate disclaimer. It did not work (i.e. no display of affiliate disclaimer) and since then the url shows on the home page for grid posts

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is in **home.php** file in your theme folder.

Maybe you can share the code of that file so that I can help you.